# Python - Selenium going through array

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I would like to do automated script. I define an array in start of the program. 
Later program is opening browser and search in google some specific word (for example apple), next program is clicking in first of string from array and close browser. Later is doing the same but it will click in second of word from array.
My code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()




hasla = ["ispot","myapple"]

for slogan in hasla:
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")

    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys("apple")
    search_field.submit()
    name = driver.find_element_by_link_text(slogan)
    name.click()
    driver.quit()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

When Im starting this program from console in windows.
Program is opening browser, looking for apple click in ispot and clsoe browser but its not opening new browser and it not doing the same for next string in array. Any solution ?

In console i have this:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU7Pf.png)

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: When Im starting this program from console in windows, program is opening browser, looking for apple click in ispot and close browser but its not opening new browser and it not doing the same for next string in array. Any solution ?

Comment: you're sending too many requests from same ip address in short period of time. Apple is refusing your connection (judging by the image you attached). Try implementing time.sleep(5) to wait 5 seconds before your next request.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description. This will also help future users who have the same problem as you. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You're exiting the browser in your for loop, so the second iteration can't do anything because there's not a browser open. You could try opening a new tab and closing the old one if you need to start fresh each time. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

hasla = ["ispot","myapple"]

for slogan in hasla:
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")

    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys("apple")
    search_field.submit()
    name = driver.find_element_by_link_text(slogan)
    name.click()

    # Save the current tab id
    old_handle = driver.current_window_handle

    # Execute JavaScript to open a new tab and save its id
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    new_handle = driver.window_handles[-1]

    # Switch to the old tab and close it
    driver.switch_to.window(old_handle)
    driver.close()

    # Switch focus to the new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(new_handle)
```

If you are closing the tab you won't be able to see the results. You might want to keep it open and just go to the new tab. In which case, just remove `driver.close()`.

Alternatively, if you really want to completely close out the browser each time and reopen it, you just need to include the first three lines in your for-loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

hasla = ["ispot","myapple"]

for slogan in hasla:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")

    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys("apple")
    search_field.submit()
    name = driver.find_element_by_link_text(slogan)
    name.click()
    driver.quit()
```

---

To answer your second question:

First, import NoSuchElementException:

`from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Then replace your try/except with this:

```
    try:
        name = driver.find_element_by_link_text(slogan)
        name.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('No such element')
    driver.quit()
```

It's still going to close the browser and go to the next iteration if the element is found or not.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand this, but i have problem because i have error like 'unindent does not match any outer indentation level' and I dont see where I have exact code and problem is under 'except NoSuchElementException:'  I put also  tab before 'driver.quit()', but still dont work.

Comment: If you know which line the error is on, put your cursor at the end of the line prior, click delete until they are one line, and then press enter. Most IDE's will auto indent the line for you. If you're using tabs and white spaces inconsistently, you might get an error. Here's the official documentation: [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) and here's a helpful article: [Structuring with Indentation](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php). Hope this helps!